# Creating multiple bar charts dynamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts

I'm making a webapp whose dashboard has a window which will have bar charts.

```
Agent       customer      time
1             aa           40 mins
2             aa           4 hours
1             ab           45 mins
2             ab           3 hours
1             ac           5 hours
2             ac           10 mins
```

As you can see that time unit can be different, so I came to a decision that I will make chart per customer. So for 1 chart my label will be `aa` and chart series data will be `1, 40 mins` and `2,4 hours`.
As you can see I have to create total 3 charts in above case.

I read in some previous threads that we can generate such dynamic charts by using `<p:datagrid>`.

```
<p:dataGrid id="timegapdatagrid" value="#{dashboardController.chartlist}">
                <p:panel id="timegap" header="Time gap Diagram" styleClass="ui-dashboard-layout">
                    <p:chart id="timeGapDiagram" type="bar" model="#{dashboardController.dashboardView.timeGapDiagram}" 
                         styleClass="ui-diagram-layout" responsive="true" parent="timegapdatagrid" binding="timegapdatagrid"/>      
                </p:panel>
         </p:dataGrid>
```

```
private void createTimeGapDiaLineModels(JourneyDTO journeyDTO) {
        dashboardView.getTimeGapDiagram().clear();
        List<TouchPointDTO> tplist = getTouchPointList(journeyDTO);
        ChartSeries cs;
        String a1=null;
        int b1=0;
        Map<String, ChartSeries> mapcs = new HashMap<>();

        TouchPointFieldResearcherListDTO touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList = journeyService.getTouchPointFiedlResearcherListOfJourney(journeyDTO);
        for (int i = 0; i<tplist.size(); i++){
            cs = new ChartSeries();
            String n1 = tplist.get(i).getTouchPointDesc();
            cs.setLabel(n1);
            for (int j=0; j<touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().size(); j++){
                if (touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getTouchpointDTO().getTouchPointDesc().equals(tplist.get(i).getTouchPointDesc()))
                {
                    a1= touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getFieldResearcherDTO().getSdtUserDTO().getUsername();
                    System.out.println(touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getFieldResearcherDTO().getSdtUserDTO().getUsername());
                    System.out.println(touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getDuration());

                    if (touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getDuration()==null){
                        System.out.println("here");
                        b1=0;  
                    }else {
                        b1 = touchPointFieldResearcherDTOList.getTouchPointFieldResearcherDTOList().get(j).getDuration();
                    }
                }
                cs.set(a1,b1);
                }
            mapcs.put(n1, cs);
            }

            //dashboardView.getTimeGapDiagram().addSeries(cs);

        for (Map.Entry<String, ChartSeries> mapChartSeries : mapcs.entrySet()) {   
            System.out.println(mapChartSeries.getValue().getLabel());

            System.out.println(mapChartSeries.getValue().getData());
            dashboardView.getTimeGapDiagram().addSeries(mapChartSeries.getValue());
    }
    }
```

It will be great help if I can get some help on the above issue.

Comment: and the problem is ???

Comment: Problem is i am not able to make it work.....can someone please share a piece of code with some description about how it works.